# Django get_queryset method's unittest failing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am working on writing unit testcases for web based application which is written in django. For unittesting of django classes I am using TestCase class available from django.test.

Now When I test get_queryset() method by client.get() method it returns error:

raise DatabaseError('This query is not supported by the database.')
DatabaseError: This query is not supported by the database.

here is my method which I am trying to test:

```
class IngredientAll(generics.ListAPIView):
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
model = Ingredient
serializer_class = IngredientListSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    userCompanyId = self.request.user.get_profile().companyId
    ingredients = Ingredient.objects.filter(company = userCompanyId)
    return ingredients
```

and here is testcase I am writing for the same:

```
class IngredientAllTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.user=User(username='jimish')
    password = 'password'
    self.user.set_password(password)
    self.user.save()

    self.client = Client()
    self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password=password)


def test_IngredientAll(self):
    url = reverse('lib:ingredient-all')
    response = self.client.get(url)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

There is no error at url reversing, that I can assure you. I have checked it from python shell. here is url pattern:

```
url(r'^allingredients$', views.IngredientAll.as_view(), name='ingredient-all'),
```

Error is showing at

```
response = self.client.get(url)
```

it would be great if someone help me with this, i will be very much thankful.

This is full traceback of error:

> $python manage.py test lib.tests:IngredientAllTestCase

$ python manage.py test lib.tests:IngredientAllTestCase

## E

### ERROR: test_IngredientAll (lib.tests.IngredientAllTestCase)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Apache2\htdocs\iLab\api\lib\tests.py", line 94, in test_IngredientAll
    response = self.client.get(url)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 442, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 244, in get
    return self.request(**r)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 111, in get_response

```
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djangorestframework-2.3.8-py2.7.egg\rest_framework\compat.py", line 127, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 39, in wrapped_view
    resp = view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 52, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djangorestframework-2.3.8-py2.7.egg\rest_framework\views.py", line 399, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djangorestframework-2.3.8-py2.7.egg\rest_framework\views.py", line 396, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Apache2\htdocs\iLab\api\lib\views.py", line 431, in get
    return Response(serializer.data)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djangorestframework-2.3.8-py2.7.egg\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 505, in data
    self._data = [self.to_native(item) for item in obj]

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 107, in _result_iter
    self._fill_cache()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 774, in _fill_cache
    self._result_cache.append(self._iter.next())

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 275, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\djangotoolbox\db\basecompiler.py", line 225, in results_iter
    self.check_query()

File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\djangotoolbox\db\basecompiler.py", line 273, in check_query
    raise DatabaseError('This query is not supported by the database.')

DatabaseError: This query is not supported by the database.

-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------

django.request: ERROR: Internal Server Error: /allingredients

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djangorestframework-2.3.8-py2.7.egg\rest_framework\compat.py", line 127, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 39, in wrapped_view
    resp = view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 52, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djangorestframework-2.3.8-py2.7.egg\rest_framework\views.py", line 399, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djangorestframework-2.3.8-py2.7.egg\rest_framework\views.py", line 396, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Apache2\htdocs\iLab\api\lib\views.py", line 431, in get
    return Response(serializer.data)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djangorestframework-2.3.8-py2.7.egg\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 505, in data
    self._data = [self.to_native(item) for item in obj]

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 107, in _result_iter
    self._fill_cache()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packanosetests lib.tests:IngredientAllTestCase --verbosity=1
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

ges\django\db\models\query.py", line 774, in _fill_cache
    self._result_cache.append(self._iter.next())

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 275, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():

File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\djangotoolbox\db\basecompiler.py", line 225, in results_iter
    self.check_query()

File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\djangotoolbox\db\basecompiler.py", line 273, in check_query

```
raise DatabaseError('This query is not supported by the database.')
```

DatabaseError: This query is not supported by the database.

--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------

---

Ran 1 test in 0.900s

Comment: post the full error stack trace if  you could please.

Comment: trackback for error added

Comment: For POST method tests are running fine.. but problem is with GET method... that's what I have observed from all testcases

Comment: Wait... you're using a non-relational database?

Comment: Yes, I am using mongoDB non-relational database

Comment: could you add your Ingredient model code to the question please? (and maybe tidy up the formatting a little :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help I found solution.

There was another model UserProfile containing companyId and role and relation to django User class.

I just needed to add those attributes to my setUp() function.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(IngredientAll, self).get_queryset()
    userCompanyId = self.request.user.get_profile().companyId
    queryset = queryset.filter(company=userCompanyId)
    return queryset
```

Comment: Tried but Error stays same.. see error traceback I have edited in my question